# Is given by(:) <eqn>; acquires the form of(:) <eqn>

Tags: punctuation, colons

Does one need to put a colon in the following cases?

The equation of motion is given by:

```
                        <eqn>
```

The equation of motion takes / acquires the form of:

```
                        <eqn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *of,* the sense just runs on. There is no need to separate *of* from the equation with punctuation; even the new line is only needed to help typesetting (and perhaps to make the equation easier to find in the page).

With *by,* the colon could be introducing a list, even if it's just a list of one item. Swan has

> A colon can introduce a list.
>
> > The main points are as follows: (1) ... , (2) ... , (3) ... .
> > We need three kinds of support: economic, moral and political.
>
> — *Practical English Usage 3rd Edition,* Michael Swan, pub OUP 2005

...so *by* could be followed by a colon. However, since it's a list with only one entry, it's probably preferable for it not to be used and for the sense to follow on in the same way as *of.*